# Change Drupal's hashing method

Tags: drupal, hash, passwords

Is it possible to change Drupal's hashing method for passwords?

Comment: without hacking the core ;)

Comment: Yes it's possible. Please post details of your research efforts so far, the code you've tried, problems encountered etc. (and what version of Drupal you're using)

Comment: We need to rewrite a prototype (and therefore migrate data - like the password hashes ;) ) and are looking for possibilities on how to achieve that (selfmade cms, drupal, joomla, ...). I did not do any research on specific code yet as I only want to get an overview of what is possible and what is not.
So it is possible without hacking too much around?

Comment: Yeah there's a mechanism implemented for just that, you'll find more details on the [password.inc docs page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21password.inc/7)